# a few questions regarding innerHTML

Tags: javascript, iframe, innerhtml, window.open, document.write

I am converting an old programmer's joke program created here in Brazil that is simmilar to [MIT's SCIgen](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/) but using artistic jargon instead of businnes gibberish.

As the program is far too old (geocities era old) it uses lots of document.write instead of innerHTHML of course.

First question is, is it safe to place like tons of code inside of innerHTMLs? As the original program loads 4 sets of arrays with every possible piece of text that can be combined to form a pseudo-essay, this is a piece of code:

```
new_window.document.write("<body bgcolor=\"#000000\">");
new_window.document.write("<body text=\"#00FF00\">")
new_window.document.write("<p align=\"center\"><b>"+atitle+"</b><hr></p>");

firstshot = 1;
paragraph = 0;
while(lines > 0) {
    if (firstshot == 1) {
        if (lines % 101 == 0 && lines % 19 == 0) {
            new_window.document.write(tab0.chr(1,0)+tab0.chr(0,1)+tab3.chr(0,0)
.....
...
```

this continues in a inch long non nested chunk of code, the entire code is here http://jsfiddle.net/jmqdx09g/

I'm experimenting and this is what I got so far:

```
<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
    <div id = "myDiv"></div>
    <span id = "mySpan"></span>
    <br>

    <button id="restore">restore</button>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="remove" id="remove" value="remove">
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var message =      
        '<li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="../about">About</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="../contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="../works/index.html">Works</a></li>'+
        ' <li><a href="../projects/index.html">Projects</a></li>'+
        '<li><a href="../curriculum/index.html">Curriculum</a></li>'

    var message2 =      
         '<div class="content">'+ 
         '<iframe src="/yourpage.html"  frameborder="0" width="600" height="650" scrolling="no">'+
         '<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>'+
         '</iframe></div>'

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = message;  // use innerHTML for block and inline HTML elements
    document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function ()
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = message2;
    });

    document.getElementById("restore").addEventListener("click", function ()
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = message;
    });
```

and it works as expected which is load a few html stuff, on a press of a button stuff is replaced by an iframe

is the iframe the best solution for this or replacing the entire html with js is the way to go?

the 
    var message = 
        'somecode'+
        'somecode'+

looks safe until now, but as far as I get into the converting, am I going to have headaches or this method is straight forward as it looks like?

should I use window.onload instead of replacing the content holder div?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is unsafe, but it is really bad way to go indeed... Why do you need to build the view using JS, why not HTML instead? (`--headeaches;`)

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by building the view using html? I tought I Was, I'm a little bit confuse now, can you be a little more specific? Give me the hint and I'll do the homework.

Comment: Well you're writing HTML using JS, that's not what's the most common. Usually all the html code is inside a .html file. As Sten wrote on his post, that's not maintanable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents worth...

> Is it safe to place like tons of code inside of innerHTMLs?

Safe, yes... Easily maintainable, no. Front end code is for the client so if they choose to hack themselves let them... Of course anything that is sent back to the server should be sanitised and not trusted, but that is a completely different issue.

In my opinion the greatest problem is maintainability.

Next the JS, refactor this into a separate file, start caching variables makes the code easier to look at.

Finally, do you need the iFrame? Or a new window? Couldn't you simply append the "artistic jargon" to the bottom of the current html? Thus saving the headache of the iframes.

I am a complete advocate of non-jQuery, but maybe for you using jQuery's HTML editing API might be a great idea. Could help to abstract some issues into a more readable and maintainable form. Then again, vanilla JS is really awesome and if it can be done that way its a great way to learn.

Comment: Great! Never tought going this way, I was wondering how people could manage content wo iframes. Having the stuff in separate files seems the best way to go, thanks for the insight.